# Strange behavior of \footnotesize in title page

Tags: titles, fontsize, size, prelim2e

Can anyone explain a rather strange behavior of `\footnotesize` in this example?

The `prelim2e`’s bottom marker text size is bigger for title page than for further ones. Sizing commands other than `\footnotesize` (like `\normalsize`, `\tiny` etc.) produce even-sized text results for all pages. This happens when using ordinary `book` class as well as for `scrbook` and more sophisticated styles like, e.g., `classicthesis`. This suggests that the underlying cause lies in some basic level (La)TeX macros (maybe inside `\maketitle` command?), but I could not find it. The expected solution would be a hack/patch resulting in `\footnotesize`-based markers of equal size on all pages.

Below is an exemplary result showing different text size of the title page’s marker.

[image]

[image]

The code for such an undesired result:

```
%\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\documentclass[12pt,headinclude,footinclude]{scrbook}%\documentclass[headinclude,footinclude,a4paper]{scrbook}

%\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{prelim2e}%\usepackage[draft]{prelim2e}
\renewcommand{\PrelimText}{\footnotesize[\,Test: this is \texttt{PrelimText}~test\,]}

\title{Title string}
\author{Author Name}


\begin{document}

%\begingroup
%\fontsize{12pt}{14.4pt}\selectfont
%\KOMAoptions{fontsize=12pt}
\maketitle
%\endgroup

%\KOMAoptions{fontsize=12pt}
%\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter title}
\section{Section title}

Some text.\newpage
Some more text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I wouldn't bother at all, as that part will eventually vanish. Interesting question anyway.

Comment: Probably I would not have even noticed this, if not for the fact that in my document the marker text is long enough to go beyond the border of the title page (the first one to be seen in print) while it almost perfectly fits the margins later.

Answer (score 4):

If a document class is built on top of a LaTeX standard class (`article`, `book`, `report`), *and* if the title is to be typeset in a separate page, then the meaning of `\footnotesize` will be locally changed.

Indeed, on Page 22 of [Standard Document Classes for LaTeX version 2e](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/classes.pdf) we find the following definition

```
\let\footnotesize\small
```

which is marked as line 546. This change is local and it only affects how footnotes such as `\thanks` appear in the *separate* title page.

Answer (score 1):

So, after the explanation from Ruixi Zhang, I was able to solve the issue in a quite trivial way as:

```
\documentclass[12pt,headinclude,footinclude]{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{prelim2e}
\let\orgfootnotesize\footnotesize
\renewcommand{\PrelimText}{\orgfootnotesize[\,Test: this is \texttt{PrelimText}~test\,]}

\title{Title string}
\author{Author Name}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\chapter{Chapter title}
\section{Section title}

\end{document}
```